# Animating CATextLayer string property

Tags: iphone, animation, catextlayer

I am trying to animate CATextLayer's string property so I can put a timestamp to my video using AV Foundation. Does anyone know how to animate this so I can change the string value every second??

Answer (score 2):

```
NSString *labelText = @"foobar";
[textLayer setString:labelText];
```

This must be run on the main thread, so I use this:

```
 NSString *labelText = @"foobar";
[textLayer performSelector:@selector(setString:) withObject:labelText waitUntilDone:YES];
```

And if you are updating frequently, you should disable the animations between the text changes:

```
NSString *labelText = @"foobar";    
[CATransaction begin];
[CATransaction setValue:(id)kCFBooleanTrue forKey:kCATransactionDisableActions];
[textLayer performSelector:@selector(setString:) withObject:labelText waitUntilDone:YES];
[CATransaction commit];
```

Comment: Thanks, but I dont think this would help. What I am trying to do is to add timestamps to videos (like survalance videos with date and time on ) and then export CATextLayer with my video to .mov file. So I don't really play the video or the CATextLayer to the screen. What I am looking for is something that can do a synchronized change to the string value in CATextLayer with my video when I do my video composition export, something like CAKeyframeAnimation which I can add to my CATextLayer (but I am not sure how to set it up or if it would solve my problem..) Thanks!